# Inconsistent behavior of jQuery selectors on goodreads site

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-parsing

Trying to extract quotes from [goodreads site](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes) and met inconsistent behavior. For example go to this page: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?page=56
and run this selector in Chrome console: `jQuery(".quote")` you will get a list of nodes where quote of Mark Twain:

> “Everyone is a moon, and has a dark side which he never shows to anybody.”
> ― Mark Twain

Is the second one, you can visually see that it's the second.

But when you run:
`jQuery(".quotes .quote:nth-of-type(2)")` it returns nothing, and only if you run `jQuery(".quotes .quote:nth-of-type(3)")` it returns Mark Twain's quote which supposed to be second, not third.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Try: `jQuery(".quotes :nth-of-type(2)").is(".quote")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the elements on that page, and you get:

[image]

The second element is not a `.quote`, but:

```
<div data-react-class="ReactComponents.NativeAd" ... ></div>
```

So `.quotes .quote:nth-of-type(2)` does not select anything, because none of the `.quote` elements are the second child of the `.quotes` parent; that's where the advertisement is.

`.quotes .quote:nth-of-type(3)` selects the second quote because the ad is in between the first and second quote, so the second quote is actually the 3rd child of its parent.

Remember that `nth-of-type` selects the nth *tag name*. Here, since all the children are `<div>`s, `.quotes .quote:nth-of-type(3)` selects the third `<div>`, which happens to be a `.quote`. (It does *not* select the `nth` element in the class collection)